# "Save as...", "View page source" and "View page info" options are disabled in context menu when creating a new window using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

trying to create a new window (as a pop-up) using JavaScript, the context menu of the new window has the options:

- "Save as...",
- "View page source",
- "View page info"

disabled in Chrome, Opera and IE (11) but it works fine for Firefox.

I am doing so using the instructions:

```
var j = window.open(myUrl);
j.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>my page</title></head><body> <p> ciao sample new page </p> </body> </html>");
j.document.close();
```

The same code was working in our system which was using html 4, now the whole architecture has been passed to html5.

I guess is something related to a security issue but why it does work in Firefox? How can I make that options stil available without writing a custom context menu? Could be a new html5 issue? Am I doing something wrong in the above code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I  fixed just using window.open(myPage);

more precisely I had a POST calling via JS and then I was writing the server response using window.write() which caused the problem to me. (anyway the sample I wrote above does not work even in a simple html page with a bit of JS to me).

So I left the POST method that save the page server side, then response returns the id of the html page I wanted to render and then I did:

```
window.open("myUrl?pageId=" + response.serverResponse.responseText, 'myPage');
```

which works fine to me without writing other code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code using HTML 4.0 and it worked the same way. I think that this is because of the way view source is handled in Chrome and the other mentioned browsers. In these browsers a refresh is made before view source operations and this is by design. If you want to view source, you can inspect element and it should work fine. It is not a security issue I believe. Can you post the exact HTML 4.0 code that used to be working and that is not working now?

Comment: In html 4 was working for me as well. Now we updated everithing to HTML5 and the problem came across. Indeed that one was only an example but you can see the "<!DOCTYPE html>" doctype which means, we are in HTML5. Anyway, I think it's a browser security issue on the write() method which I fixed differently, but thank you.